# Destructor called twice with Return Value Optimization

Tags: c++, destructor, return-value-optimization

In order to understand [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) I wrote a small example

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { cout << "constructor was called" << endl; }
    ~Foo() { cout << "destructor was called" << endl; }
};

Foo f()
{
    Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

int main()
{
    
    Foo bla = f();
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
constructor was called
destructor was called
destructor was called
```

As I understand it, in the `f()` function the `foo` object is constructed directly in the memory space where `bla` is allocated so the constructor is called only once. I understand that when we exit the `main()` function, the `bla` object goes out of scope and the destructor is called. But why is the destructor called twice? Is the destructor of `foo` called when we exit the scope of the `f()` function even though the object is not destroyed and used by the caller?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  You are using NRVO, which is not guaranteed, not RVO.  To get RVO change `f` to `return Foo{};` or just `return {};`

Comment: Copy elision is not guaranteed for named variables.  Your output indicates that the copy was __not__ elided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with return value optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584352/issue-with-return-value-optimisation)

Comment: You forgot to log the copy constructor call.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled? If not, it is not surprising that the compiler didn't elide the copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also added logging of copy constructor in the code, to illustrate what happens.

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { cout << "constructor was called" << endl; }
    Foo(const Foo&) {cout << "copy constructor was called" << endl;}
    ~Foo() { cout << "destructor was called" << endl; }
};

Foo f()
{
    Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

int main()
{
    
    Foo bla = f();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
constructor was called
copy constructor was called
destructor was called
destructor was called
```

So we see that from two possible object construction both took place, and one used `copy-constructor`.

If we turn on optimizations, we get

```
constructor was called
destructor was called
```

Now the object is constructed once directly in memory space, and the destructor is called once. Here is a [DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/Kcrv449es)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still confused. Once the copy constructor is called, we are already into the scope of main() and so we have only the bla object left. Why is the destructor then called twice? (I am talking about the first output)

Comment: In the first output, two objects are created.  First is created via the no arg constructor, and the second is created via the copy constructor.  Both objects have to be individually destroyed.  If you modify the logging functions to print the values of `this`, you will see there are two separate objects being created and destroyed.

Comment: @DaveS, but doesn't the destructor of the first created object has to be called before the constructor of the second created object? Indeed once we evaluate the expression f(), the first object is already out of scope so it should be destructed before the assignment no?

Comment: No, when the copying takes place, the first object still exists as temporary. Once the copying ends, the destructor of the first object is called. If the destructor of the first object was called before the constructor of the second object, the second object would have nothing to copy from.

Comment: Oh, right, that makes sense. Thanks! Also I was confused because in MSVC, NRVO is applied by default and to remove it we need the `/Zc:nrvo-` compiler option. This is true for MSVC 2022 but in MSVC 2019 nrvo is turned off by default